# BAWSAQ market doesn't seem to move but social club graphs indicate it is

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've completed the GTA 5 main story missions and now I'm trying to make more money by playing the stock market. I bought shares in Whiz and I'm waiting for them to change. Every time I look either online or in game the share price is unchanged at 0.57.

I checked on social club yesterday and they were at 0.57 with the graph reflecting this, although they were higher on Thursday according to the graph. Today they're also 0.57 but the graph shows they were about 1.0 yesterday, but they definitely weren't whenever I looked.

Social club's also showing Michael's portfolio as owning 0 shares for me even though I have about 1.5 million shares on that character.

I read that it can sometimes get stuck in game and you need to reload a save to fix it, and I've tried that, with no luck. Does anyone know if it's generally glitching/broken or a known issue with a workaround?